# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (REACT NATIVE - Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, app

He estado tratando de importar un archivo Json para luego recorrerlo y mostrarlo en una app de React Native.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Json es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el error que me sale.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código, estoy recién aprendiendo React Native, y a la vez Javascript.

Comment: Saludos, las imagenes de codigo no son buenas practicas para este sitio, deberias de colocar el codigo como texto, NO como imagen, para poder replicar el problema. aunque tu problema ya se vé, seria bueno que [edites](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/342622/edit) tu pregunta para poder responderte y darte la solucion.

Answer (score 0):

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) es un función propia de javascript, mas específicamente de los `array`.

Tendiendo es en cuenta eso, el error: **map of undefined** sucede porque a la variable a la que le aplicas `map` no es un array.

Y eso se nota claramente en tu archivo `'./Events'`, el cual es un objeto y no un array.

Un objeto tiende a iniciarse con llaves `{}`, en cambio un array con corchetes `[]`. Y tu archivo `'./Events'` esta asi:

```
{
    "events":[
         {
          ....
         },
         {
          ....
         }
    ]
}
```

Entonces es un objeto y NO un array.

Entonces debes de acceder al array mas o menos asi:

```
this.state.events.events.map(...Lo que tengas de codigo)
```

Hay muchas otras cosillas por observar pero por lo pronto espero que eso te funcione.