# this.state.x.map is not a function en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hago una llamada a una API que me devuelve una coleccion de objetos JSON y quiero meter estos objetos en el estado del componente.

He probado varias aparentes soluciones y no me ha funcionado ninguna. El caso es que he logueado el estado cuando el componente se carga y es efectivamente un array:

```js
async componentDidMount(){

 axios.get(`https://c6tdkwn8v7.execute-api...`)
  .then((res) => {
       const gallery = JSON.stringify(res.data);
       this.setState({
          galleries: gallery
       })
   
console.log(this.state.galleries)// Devuelve:

[{"name":"Miami","coordinates":[25.7616798,-80.1917902],"id":3},{"name":"Seattle","coordinates":[47.6062095,-122.3320708],"id":2},{"name":"Nueva York","coordinates":[40.7127753,-74.0059728],"id":1}]

}
```

Pero cuando intento renderizarlo me dice `this.state.galleries.map is not a function`:

```js
 {this.state.galleries.map((item, key) =>
    <li item={item.name} key={item.id} />
  )}
```

Añado Código completo:

```js
export default class UserGallery extends Component {

    state = {
        authenticatedUser: "",
        galleries: []
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const session = await Auth.currentSession();
        const userEmail = session.idToken.payload.email
        axios.get(`https://c6tdkwn8v7.execute-api...`)
        .then((res) => {
           
            const gallery = JSON.stringify(res.data);
            this.setState({
                galleries: gallery
            })
            console.log(this.state.galleries)
        })
    }

    renderSites = () => {
        if(this.state.galleries.length > 0 ) {
            return this.state.galleries.map(site => (
                <div className="added-items-container">
                    <Container className="bg-dark text-white card-site">
                        <Row>
                            <Col sm={8}>
                                <p>
                                    Viaje a {site.name}
                            <br />
                            Fuiste el 13 de Marzo al 19 Marzo de 2012
</p>
                            </Col>
                            <Col><Image src={italyPic} height="70px" rounded alt="Card image" />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                </div>
            ))}
      
        return null
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="usergallery-container">
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col className="search-gallery-col-1">
                            <Container className="search-gallery-container">

                                <Form>
                                    <h4>Busca una galeria </h4>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col className="search-gallery-form" sm={8}>
                                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="ejemplo: Madrid, New York...etc" />
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col sm={2}>
                                            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" variant="success">Buscar</Button>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </Form>
                                
                                {this.renderSites()}

                            </Container>
                        </Col>
                               

                        <Col className="search-gallery-col-2" xs={7}>
                            <h4>Ultimo añadido</h4>
                            <Carousel>
                                <Carousel.Item>
                                    <img
                                        className="d-block w-100"
                                        src={brazilPic}
                                        alt="First slide"
                                    />
                                    <Carousel.Caption>
                                        <h3>Viaje a Brasil</h3>

                                    </Carousel.Caption>
                                </Carousel.Item>
                                <Carousel.Item>
                                    <img
                                        className="d-block w-100"
                                        src={francePic}
                                        alt="Third slide"
                                    />

                                    <Carousel.Caption>
                                        <h3>Viaje a Francia</h3>

                                    </Carousel.Caption>
                                </Carousel.Item>
                                <Carousel.Item>
                                    <img
                                        className="d-block w-100"
                                        src={italyPic}
                                        alt="Third slide"
                                    />

                                    <Carousel.Caption>
                                        <h3>Viaje a Italia</h3>

                                    </Carousel.Caption>
                                </Carousel.Item>
                            </Carousel>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Edito: Acabo de hacer `typeof`y me dice que es una string. Lo he convertido a array añadiéndole JSON.parse(x) pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: hace unas horas respondi a esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342622/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-react-native-java/342659#342659, en tu caso galery podria ser null

Comment: No veo esta parte del codigo `{this.state.galleries.map((item, key) =>     <li item= {item.name} key={item.id} />  )}` en el codigo completo que publicaste. Donde lo tienes?

Comment: @Einer Espera, lo voy a actualizar todo bien el OP y re-escribirlo desde cero. Creo que ya he cogido donde esta el problema.

Comment: Ya está resuelto. Eran dos problemas. Uno, que lo que creía que era un array, era una string. Y otro, que efectivamente como dijo el usuario @Isaac , el html se ponía renderizar antes que el array estuviese relleno, lo cual daba error y se soluciona con su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque el componente intenta renderear la lista cuando aun `galleries` no tiene la info, lo que podrias hacer es validar que `galleries` tenga la info para despues hacer el mapeo. Podrias crear un funcion y ahi hacer la validacion

```
renderList = () => {
  if(this.state.galleries.length > 0 ) {
    return this.state.galleries.map((item, key) =>
        <li item={item.name} key={item.id} />
      )
  }

  return null
}

render() {
    return (
        {this.renderList()}
    )
}
```

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error incluso después de implentar tu solución, de verdad que me esta volviendo loco ya no se que puede ser. Crees que puede ser por el async del componentDidMount?

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado añadiendo por mi parte también el JSON.parse() porque no era un array lo que pensaba, sino una string.

Answer (score 0):

Por el momento lo unico raro que veo es que usas stringify, cuando creo que lo que buscas es parse. Creo que te dice que map no es una funcion porque se convierte en un string. Suerte!